# Refresh the window with current page

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I created my Index page with an iframe. All other pages 
(Home,Services, About us, Contact Us) contents were linked to that iframe and all are opened via that iframe.

When opening the Index page, defaultly open the Home Page through the iframe. When I am in the About us, and click the refresh button, it is directed to the Home page. I want to stay in the currently open page when click the browser refresh button. How to fix this ???

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and CODE

Comment: Have a look at `window.location.hash`.  Set that when you change page, and check it on page load in order to decided what page to show in the iframe.

Comment: You can use cookies or localStorage too to retain the last loaded page

Comment: I am new to web design. So i need a clear answer that describes the ways such as where should i place code.